# Angular 7: como identificar o encode de um arquivo?

Tags: angular, typescript, arquivo, upload, file-upload

Eu tenho uma função que roda ao ser feito o upload de arquivos, gostaria de identificar o tipo do encode deste. Estou utilizando o código abaixo.

```
async uploadFile(event) {
    var document;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    let file = event.target.files[0];

    reader.onload = ((file: any) => {
      return (e: any) => {
        document.description = e.srcElement.result;
        document.title = title;
        document.fileName = file.name;
      }
    })(file);

    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
```

Alguma ideia ?

Obrigada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma biblioteca pra lhe ajudar:
https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js

Se você quiser, pode usar a definição types dessa biblioteca, que está disponível em:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/encoding-japanese

Exemplo de uso:

```
import * as Encoding from 'encoding-japanese';

var detected = Encoding.detect(utf8Array);
if (detected === 'UTF8') {
  console.log('Encoding is UTF-8');
}
```